# Swapping identical location references with a single variable in json

Tags: javascript, json, variables, base64, data-uri

I'm trying to create, I'm assuming a variable within JSON - My application has multiple references to **"images/sprite-sheet1.png"** Which I manually convert to base64 data URI strings.

I am able to put "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB=" in where the "images/sprite-sheet1.png" are but, including the same URI string multiple times, bloats my file size.

Is there a way to better handle this?  I assumed I could create a variable and call it where the sprite sheet locations are - but that doesn't seem to work.

I tried

```
var spriteSheet1 = ["data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB="]
```

and than

```
"ctaButton", 0, false, [], 0, null, [
            ["tapToSelect", 0, false, 1, 0, false, 725708356016635, [
                [spriteSheet1, 1, 2, [],
                    [1, 2], 0
                ]
            ]]
        ]
```

Which doesn't work.
Below is a snip it of the multiple references to the exact same sprite sheet - Ideally I would like to store the data URI strings of the images and then call via a variable or something similar if possible.

```
{
"project": ["project name", "gameMain", [
        [0, false],
        [2, false],
        [3, true],
        [4, true]
    ],
    [
        ["ctaButton", 0, false, [], 0, null, [
            ["tapToSelect", 0, false, 1, 0, false, 725708356016635, [
                ["images/sprite-sheet1.png", 1, 2, [],
                    [1, 2], 0
                ]
            ]]
        ],
        [], false, true, 626047515185758, [], null
    ],
    ["logo", 0, false, [], 0, null, [
            ["logoAnim", 5, false, 1, [
                ["images/sprite-sheet1.png", 1, 2, [],
                    [1, 2], 0
                ]
            ]]
        ],
        [], false, true, 386961897579956, [], null
    ]
    ]
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. “JSON” stands for “JavaScript Object Notation,” which means it’s a notation language, and not a scripting language. As such, there is no real way to compress a JSON stream in the way that you’re trying to—not natively, anyway. This is why JSON stringify can fail if your object references itself.

I’m sure a library exists somewhere to compress the JSON, but unless you have control over both the sending and receiving scripts, you run the risk of compatibility issues.